# GSUTIL for window

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have a problem to copy file from Google cloud storage to my local machine. Below is the command that I run:

**gsutil -m cp "gs://database/Cloud_SQL_Export_2017-09-19 (11:41:09)" .**

The error that I get is as below:

**Copying gs://database/Cloud_SQL_Export_2017-09-19 (11:41:09)...
==> NOTE: You are downloading one or more large file(s), which would
run significantly faster if you enabled sliced object downloads. This
feature is enabled by default but requires that compiled crcmod be
installed (see "gsutil help crcmod").
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('ab') or filename: u'.\Cloud_SQL_Export_2017-09-19 (11:41:09)_.gstmp'
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.**

Hope that someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it required a third party download: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crcmod

But it might also need some escapes around the parenthesis and other symbols:

```
"gs://database/Cloud_SQL_Export_2017-09-19\ \(11\:41\:09\)" .
```

Comment: I've already download the crcmod but still the same. After putting the escape as suggested, I'm getting this error:  CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://database/Cloud_SQL_Export_2017-09-19\ \(11\:41\:09\)
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.